# Add social login (Google and Facebook) to an existing Android Login

Tags: android, node.js, facebook-login, google-signin

I have an existing Android App which you can create and account and log in through username/email and password and now I want to be able to create an account and login with social platforms like Google or Facebook.

My Android app connects to the DB though a NodeJS API that we made. This API has a route xxxxx/authenticate where you send your email/username and password and it returns you a token.

My question is how I can add Google and Facebook login to this setup that we have and add session management.

I've tried to do [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and I've been able to log in through Google, but my problem is that all my API queries are token protected and I'm stuck here right now.

I don't know if I have to modify the API in order to accept tokens from Google and Facebook or try to handle it all on App level.

Any light or advice on this matter will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your api sends token on response when you have the authenticated account,  if it is so then, if someone tries to login with facebook or google first of all check the email associated with the DB, if not then forward them to signup activity to create an account.. later link their account  and next time if they try to login with fb or google... it will be on the DB so redirect them to homepage by providing token

Answer (score 1):

> ## this is for google plus
>
> You need to add some permission ans library in Your project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private SignInButton signInButton;
        private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
        private TextView textViewName;
        private TextView textViewEmail;
        private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;
        private ImageLoader imageLoader;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    //        profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
            signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
            signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */).
                    addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
        public void sign_out(View view) {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SIGN OUT SUCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            textViewName.setText("");
                            textViewEmail.setText("");
                        }
                    });
    //        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
    //                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    //                    @Override
    //                    public void onResult(Status status) {
    //                        // ...
    //                    }
    //                });

        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        }

        private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
                textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
    //            Toast.makeText(this,acct.get)

                //Initializing image loader
    //            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
    //                    .getImageLoader();
    //
    //            imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
    //                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
    //                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
    //                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    //
    //            //Loading image
    //            profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == signInButton) {
                signIn();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated the link on my post. I've already had this that you mention and I'm able to login through google, my question is how I can get any token to access to my other API routes that are token protected and normally this token is given when I log in with email and password through my API.